# How do you get Cabal to print all available versions of a package?

Tags: haskell, cabal

How do you get Cabal to print all available versions of a package? Running `cabal -v info package-name` prints something like this; in case many versions are available:

```
Versions available: (0.1.5.5), (0.1.5.6), (0.1.6.3), (0.1.6.4), 0.1.6.5,
                    0.2.4.2, 0.2.5.0, 0.2.6.0, 0.2.7.0 (and 26 others)
```

Comment: Not command-line friendly, but you can see all the versions on Hackage. e.g. for [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) for the text package. Is that good enough?

Comment: Yes, this is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An indirect way to accomplish this, e.g. for the `text` package is

```
cabal list --simple-output text | awk '$1=="text" { print $2 }'
```

The post-processing via `awk` is needed because `cabal list` currently only supports substring matching, but not exact matching.

Comment: I don't understand how is this use of `awk` related to substring matching. It trims the package name from the results and displays their versions only (which is a nice adjustment, but not a necessary one).

Comment: @JindřichMynarz If you take a look at the output you get without the `awk` addendum, you will see there are many non-`text` results, like `texts 0.0.0` and `text-zipper 0.1` and so forth. The `awk` command simultaneously eliminates these and trims away the package name at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to get cabal to do it, but the information is at least available. Check the [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/) page for the package; typically this is `http://hackage.haskell.org/package/<package-name>`. It will include a complete list of available versions right after the package description.